# dynamic onclick link

Tags: onclick, hyperlink, string-formatting, dynamic-data

Does anyone know how to format the `li` `onclick` function when it is a dynamic variable string? Basically I just need to insert a dynamic link parameter into the `onclick` `openwindow` function. For some reason I a getting an error in ie8 and an error when clicked in firefox. I know there is a way to format this but haven't run across it yet. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
function myFunc(xml){
    var myDynamicLink = '';
    mylist += '<ul>';

    $(xml).find("group").each(function(i){//loop through groups           
        myDynamicLink = $(this).find('course').text();  

        mylist += '<li><a onclick="openwindow('+myDynamicLink+',800,600);">Go to Course</a></li>';

    }

    mylist += '</ul>';
    $('#myDiv').html(mylist);//Display to the DOM
}
```

Comment: I figured it out just needed a few backslashes and another set of single quotes.

        mylist += '<li><a onclick="openwindow(\''+myDynamicLink+'\',800,600);">Go to Course</a></li>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just needed a few backslashes and another set of single quotes.

```
mylist += '<li><a onclick="openwindow(\''+myDynamicLink+'\',800,600);">Go to Course</a></li>';
```